# I get 'no signal' on both monitors when connecting both using DVI splitter

Tags: multiple-monitors, dvi

I have two ACER V196L 19" monitors that I want to connect using DVI.

I bought a DVI splitter but when I connect both my monitors to it (via DVI) both monitors say 'no signal'

If I plug each monitor directly into the PC (i.e. 1 monitor set up) then the monitor works. This proves the monitors work ok.

If I use the DVI splitter and plug just one monitor into the splitter then the monitor works. This proves the splitter cable works ok.

I want a simple dual monitor set-up so I can have internet/email open on one screen whilst I do other work on the other screen.

At the moment I've got both screens working by connecting one monitor using VGA but it is slightly annoying as the output quality is not as good as DVI.

Any guidance? Perhaps I need a better graphics card?

Thanks

Comment: Perhaps you could add what the "splitter" device is that you're using.  This can be many different things.

Comment: A simple splitter will just split the signal; the same display on both screens. It won't allow you to have different displays on each monitor.

Comment: @ChrisInEdmonton: What would I need for different displays on each? Two separate DVI ports or a graphics card to support that?

Comment: The splitter is a `DVI - D Male to 2 x DVI - D Female Splitter Cable`. You can see it [here](http://www.amazon.co.uk/gp/product/B000P8DJJQ?psc=1&redirect=true&ref_=oh_aui_detailpage_o00_s00)

Answer (score 0):

As the description says in the link you added, "When Splitting Both Monitors Should Be Similar With The Same Screen Resolution Set".

The reason why it won't work when both monitors are plugged into the adapter, as it SHOULD, I believe is because it is a passive adapter and therefore the signal is splitted between the monitors and both signals are too weak to be "seen" by the monitors.

I also tried some DVI splitters a few years ago, with the same bad result. We ended up using active HDMI splitters instead, but again - with the same picture all places.

If you haven't got a new computer already, a new graphics card with multiple DVI, HDMI or other digital output is the solution.